# Баг Bootstrap 3 со скроллом модального окна на iOS (Safari). Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, input

В Bootstrap 3 у модального окна есть баг, возникающей при рендеринге положения элементов input в модальном окне в момент вызова виртуальной клавиатуры на устройствах iOS. Для решения этой проблемы обычно используют переключение элементов в `position:absolute`. Я попробовал использовать такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isiPhone = /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    if(isiPhone) {
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
            bottom: 'auto',
            });

    setTimeout( function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').css({
            position: 'absolute', 
            top: 0, 
            left: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: Math.max(
            document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
            document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
            document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
            ) + 'px'
        });
    }, 500);

    var currentscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('input').on('blur', function() {
                if (!event.relatedTarget) {
                $(window).scrollTop(currentscroll);
                }
        });
 });}});
```

В целом он работает неплохо. Модальное окно открывается в том месте, где его вызвали, исчезли неприятные скачкообразные скроллы при вызове клавиатуры. Но если страница длинная (а на мобильных устройствах она такая и получается), то перед и после модального окна появляются большие пространства, и окно скроллится вместе с содержимым страницы, что не всегда хорошо.
Можно ли как-то ограничить скролл модального окна в каких-то пределах ?

Comment: при открытии окна, на `body` вешай `overflow: none`, при закрытии возвращай `overflow: auto`

Comment: @Василий Барбашев. добавил в скрипт при открытии окна`$('body').css({
                overflow: 'none',
                });` все равно окно скроллится вместе с body.

Comment: не может быть, у окна вообще пропадет скролл, либо скролящий блок у вас другой. Другими словами, надо именно на скролящий блок вешать `overflow: none`, тогда страница не будет иметь скролл и не сможет скролится.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев. по порядку. я добавил overflow: none в существующиий скрипт (который выше). пробовал отдельно. модальное окно не скролится. но оно не скролится и без скрипта, потому-что у .modal position fixed. Но при position fixed начинаются проблемы с фокусировкой клавиатуры. Возможно overflow:none у body не срабатывает потому, что у Bootstrap есть ограничение на это дело и содержимое body будет скролится вместе с модальным окном. и обойти это не получается.

Comment: не может быть такого. уже реализовывал похожее. И кстати у окна `position:fixed`, это очень плохо, т.к. модальное окно нельзя будет скролить, если оно будет больше чем окно клиента. Бутстрап сам убирает (и должен убирать) глобальный скролл у окна и выставлять его под модальное окно. пример можно посмотреть у домсвай.рф щелкнув на калькулятор

Comment: @Василий Барбашев. посмотрел пример. возможно я не так изложил ситуацию. у модального окна свойство position по дефолту fixed. Оно прекрасно скролится, даже если его содержимое больше экрана, потому что у body overflow: auto.  в доках Bootstrap сказано о некоторых ограничениях именно на iOS. [http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards]. приходится элементу .modal менять position на absolute. тогда нет проблем с экранной клавиатурой на iOS (Safari), но получается скролл. либо оставлять у modal position fixed, но тогда будут неприятные прыжки при вызове клавиатуры.